# Jquery post define response type to json

Tags: javascript, jquery, web-services, soap, jquery-post

My post code is shown below:

```
$.post("http://xxxxxx/service/login", { phoneid: "xxx", username: "xxx"   ,password:"xx"}).done(function(data) {
      alert("Data Loaded: " + data);
    });
```

But i want to define response type to json. I'm using jquery post not ajax. I'am posting data to webservice in external javascript. I found some example for ajax post. But i want jquery post. Need starting point.

Answer (score 1):

you can pass the dataType as the last argument to [$.post()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/)

```
$.post("http://xxxxxx/service/login", { 
    phoneid: "xxx", username: "xxx",
    password:"xx"
}, 'json').done(function(data) {
    alert("Data Loaded: " + data);
});
```

Comment: Thank you for answer. I did what you say. When i look in firebug there is no respond value or answer. It is emty. And when i click xml tab i got exception:XML parse error: element not found  Location: moz-nullprincipal:{952df410-e991-4ea8-8422-22c0023d077b} Satır: 1, Sütun: 1:XML ayrıştırma hatası: eleman bulunamadı Konum: moz-nullprincipal:{952df410-e991-4ea8-8422-22c0023d077b} Satır: 1, Sütun: 1:XML ayrıştırma hatası: eleman bulunamadı Konum: moz-nullprincipal:{952df410-e991-4ea8-8422-22c0023d077b} Column: 1, Row: 1:not found.

Answer (score 0):

add JSON at the end.. to set the response as json..

```
$.post("http://xxxxxx/service/login", { phoneid: "xxx", username: "xxx"   ,password:"xx"}
       ,'JSON')
       .done(function(data) {
          alert("Data Loaded: " + data);
      });
```